# Compile NodeJS C++ modules on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, node.js, module, compilation

Is there a documentation to follow on this subject?

I wonder if I need to go to download Ubuntu and install it on a Virtual Box or if I can just skip that time wasting process and compile directly on Windows.

Has anyone tried compiling with Visual Studio or with some other tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out 
https://github.com/saary/node.net

and an example based on it @
https://github.com/gfosco/tsqlftw